# Google Maps display geoJSON from variable instead of file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

So I have a geoJSON saved in a variable or parsed as an object:

```
// geoJSON as object
var segment = segment;

// geoJSON as JSON string
var json = JSON.stringify(segment);
```

How am I able to display this on a google map? It's valid and the JSON string stored in `json` is visible when I paste it into a validator like http://geojsonlint.com/ .

Sadly, this doesn't work:

`myMap.data.loadGeoJson(json);`

And I can't find any other documentation about google maps that tells me how I could import geoJSON data directly without a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to load the data directly from a geoJSON-object is called `addGeoJson`

You'll find a description in the methods-section of  [`google.maps.Data`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)